# Does one have to make multiple blessings of "Shehakol" on hot coffee?

Tags: blessing, kavana-intent

One buys hot coffee and keeps in a thermos the entire day. When he buys it, he takes a few sips (enough to qualify to make a bracha) and has in mind that he will be sipping from the thermos throughout the day.

Since he has in mind that he will be doing this throughout the day, does he need to make an additional blessing later on, or does the 1st blessing cover all the other sips? How much time would have to elapse between sips that would require him to make another bracha?

Comment: "enough to qualify to make a bracha" What _wouldn't_ qualify?

Comment: @DoubleAA - "mouthful". I had a sense that this might be a dupe, but couldn't locate it.

Comment: Why would you not say a blessing before drinking a mouthful??

Comment: @DoubleAA Oy! I meant to say that what I meant in my Q TO qualify would be a minimum of a mouthful. Thanks for tolerating my temp. distractions :-)

Comment: Why would you not say a blessing before drinking less than a mouthful??

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65629/759